# Is it possible to add onPress event to svg graphic which was loaded from file in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

In my React Native application I need to load a svg graphic from a file and add onPress events to suitable svg elements based on element ids. I want to ask if it is possible in React Native?

To add the svg file I plan to use the solution form react-native-svg (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg#use-with-svg-files).

Comment: Did you ever find this solution? I'm having the same problem atm.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't.